# Can I refresh bootstrap tabs content when click each tabs?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap tabs as below.

HTML markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="active-all">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn active">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">D</button>
  </div>

  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="active-all">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn active">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">D</button>
  </div>

  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="active-all">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn active">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">D</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('bg-color');
    });
});
```

Basically, I toggle class bg-color button. Those button are placed in every tab I have. When I clicked on button, bg-color class is applied to button. When I return to previous tab or next tab, the style on button still there. It seems tab doesn't refresh. So is there any way make tab content refresh every time I click on tab.

Comment: what you mean by refresh ? note that tab just show and hide content here ( all the dom is mounted and just playing on visibilty )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to delete the class with the color when you visit any tab. To do this, add this part of the code:

```
$('.nav.nav-tabs a').click(function(){
    $('.btn').removeClass('bg-color');
});
```

Complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('bg-color');
  });
  $('.nav.nav-tabs a').click(function(){
      $('.btn').removeClass('bg-color');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank for your respond, This actually what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Rahwee, no problem.